# Projetos de uma Solução C#

Tags: visual-studio, organização-de-projeto

Tenho uma dúvida sobre projetos e soluções no visual studio.

Supondo que tenho uma solução que tenha três projetos, sendo dois projetos WinForms (exe) e um de bibliotecas de classe. Está correto eu ter dois projetos "exe" em uma solução que use a mesma biblioteca de classes?

Complementado:

Os dois projetos "exe" são:

1 - É uma aplicação para cadastrar clientes e outras coisas para armazenagem de caixas de arquivo morto.

2 - O segundo e a aplicação onde o usuário faz os lançamentos das caixas.

3 - É a biblioteca compartilhada.

Eu poderia juntar os dois em uma aplicação, porem o cliente quer assim, separado.

Hoje conforme eu preciso testar, eu vou e marco a aplicação como "startUp Project" e depois faço a build.

Existe uma abordagem tecnicamente melhor para isso?

Comment: Normal. E se o cliente quer, difícil convencer ele do contrário.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Está correto eu ter dois projetos "exe" em uma solução que use a mesma biblioteca de classes?

Sim, é super normal. Inclusive, eu já participei de um projeto que tinha 5 executáveis e mais alguns projetos web na mesma solução.

Ainda existe a opção de fazer várias soluções com apenas alguns *.csproj*, não acho que isso é interessante pro seu caso.

Se tiver interesse nisso, é só criar uma solução em branco e adicionar os projetos existentes que você quer nessa solução. É uma abordagem que eu tenho visto bastante quando o escopo do projeto muda drasticamente. Como, por exemplo, uma solução contendo tudo pro sistema principal e o projeto com as classes compartilhadas, outra solução com tudo pra *interface* web de gerenciamento do sistema, mais as classes compartilhadas e outra solução com os projetos *mobile* e mais as classes compartilhadas.

> Hoje conforme eu preciso testar, eu vou e marco a aplicação como "startUp Project" e depois faço a build. Existe uma abordagem tecnicamente melhor para isso?

Não sei se é tecnicamente melhor, mas ainda é possível executar vários projetos ao mesmo tempo. Indo no menu **Debug > Start new instance**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, eu realmente estava em dúvida e com medo de estar fazendo "gambiarra". Valeu.......

Answer (score 1):

> Hoje conforme eu preciso testar, eu vou e marco a aplicação como
>   "startUp Project" e depois faço a build. Existe uma abordagem
>   tecnicamente melhor para isso?

Você pode iniciar mais de um projeto na sua solução através das Propriedades da Solução > Common Properties > Startup Project > Multiple startup projects

Na coluna `Action` você seleciona a ação desejada para cada projeto.